# Power BI: place lookup values from disordered JSON objects in correct columns

Tags: json, powerbi, dax

In Power BI I have a column containing JSON. Each row contains 3 key:value pairs in the format of 3-digits:4-digits as in the below example

**Table 1**

```
{"567":"1259","568":"1535","570":"1264"}
{"393":"9521","392":"5351","394":"4621"}
```

Each key:value can be used to look up an entry in another table:

**Table 2**

```
Key | Value | Entry
-------------------
567 | 1259  | Apple
568 | 1535  | Large
570 | 1264  | Red 
393 | 9521  | Small
392 | 5351  | Pear
394 | 4621  | Green
```

I want to create 3 new columns to append to Table 1, populated with the entries looked up from table 2 like so:

```
Fruit | Size  | Colour
----------------------
Apple | Large | Red
Pear  | Small | Green
```

My go-to solution would be to `split` the JSON column into 3 by the `,` delimiter, then `merge` it with Table 2 by `Key`. However, as JSON objects are not ordered, the first key in column 1 may represent, say, fruit, whereas the first key in column 2 may represent, say, size. In this illustration, this would result in a size value in the fruit column, which is not the intention:

```
Fruit | Size  | Colour
----------------------
Apple | Large | Red
Small | Pear  | Green
```

Thankfully, there is a consistent pattern to the **order** of the key **value** and what it represents in my table 2 data. In other words, the key with the lowest value represents fruit, the key with the next highest value represents size and the key with the highest value represents colour.

As such, I thought one solution might be to find a way within Power BI to programmatically take the JSON column and order the JSON content by ascending key value.

**Example input:**

```
{"393":"1259","392":"1535","394":"1264"}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{"392": "1535","393":"1259","394": "1264"}
```

As others have pointed out this may not be the best solution to this problem, so I am open to suggestions.

I am also aware that this is down to poor database design, but here I am!

Comment: If you want to match on another table you need a key to match on, so rather than it being ordered, you need a synthetic key 1,2,3 in both tables

Comment: Reordering the fields is easy (`List.Transform(Source, each Record.ReorderFields(_, List.Sort(Record.FieldNames(_))))`, assuming `Source` is a `Json.Document` with multiple rows), but, per Nick, I suspect this is not actually what you need.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for your comment. I have updated the question to be clearer about what I am trying to achieve. Does your suggestion still apply?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated the question to be clearer about what I am trying to achieve? Do you still think reordering the fields is the best solution?

Comment: Is the collection of keys finite? You could map keys to types first (`567` is `Fruit`, `392` is `Fruit`), then look up the value. In that case no ordering is necessary since the columns can simply be expanded by name.

Comment: @JeroenMostert There is no type value in table 2, and there are thousands of keys with hundreds of unique entries with tens of unique types, so I think it would be difficult to programmatically achieve that. The database was very poorly designed for any sort of analysis, but I am trying to make it work.

Comment: Alright, then do you actually need the key or do the values happen to be unique themselves? I ask because if the key is not needed to determine the entry, the lookup would be slightly simpler. If you need the key as well to make the value unique, things get ugly. Well, *uglier*. I assume we also can't have nice things like keys always being three digits long (which would make things like string replacement an option)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to [mahoneypat](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/226208) who [answered this question on the Power BI community forum](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Look-up-values-from-disordered-JSON-objects-and-place-in-correct/m-p/2176779#M798931). I can confirm it worked.

I'm pasting his answer below so it may anyone here on Stackoverflow:

> Here's one way to do it in the query editor.  To see how it works, just create a blank query, open the Advanced Editor and replace the text there with the M code below.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("NcvLEYAgDEXRXt6aheSHsRVCJY69C0G3Z+7tHXdArQWuQCX1QFlwblDWDe34CpPAg1FyZOdkV6rZsVPC/H6QBLFVzHG8", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [JsonData = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"JsonData", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Result", each let 
thisrecord = Json.Document([JsonData]),
sortedrecord = Record.ReorderFields(thisrecord, List.Sort(Record.FieldNames(thisrecord))),
renamedrecord = Record.RenameFields(sortedrecord, List.Zip({Record.FieldNames(sortedrecord), {"Fruit", "Size", "Color"}}))
in 
renamedrecord),
    #"Expanded Result" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Result", {"Fruit", "Size", "Color"}, {"Fruit", "Size", "Color"})
in
    #"Expanded Result"
```

> The key step is the custom column with this expression. Replace [JsonData] with your actual column name with the Json string.

```
let
thisrecord = Json.Document([JsonData]),
sortedrecord = Record.ReorderFields(thisrecord, List.Sort(Record.FieldNames(thisrecord))),
renamedrecord = Record.RenameFields(sortedrecord, List.Zip({Record.FieldNames(sortedrecord), {"Fruit", "Size", "Color"}}))
in
renamedrecord
```